# How to add cppcheck to path if .exe doesn't exist?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

When I download cppcheck, it creates a folder which only contains a shortcut to cppcheck. When I right click this shortcut, and go to file location, it takes me to the same folder which only contains the shortcut.

What can I do with this to add cppcheck to my path variables so I can use cppcheck?

Comment: Surely the installer asked you where it could put its files .. did you find cppcheck there?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the installation folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Cppcheck x64 2.12

Comment: that should not be the install location.  it should be in C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86) by default

Comment: Just found it in ProgramFiles thank you Nathan

Answer (score 1):

.exe is located in C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86) by default